# Regex to detect IE 5, 6, 7 and 8 but no others

Tags: regex, browser-detection

I've put together this regex which should only return a match where the user agent string is IE 5, 6, 7 and 8. Obviously one of the main goals here is to avoid the confusing IE11 user agent string..

Is this Regex valid (have i missed something)?

```
.*MSIE [5-8]\b((?!Trident/4.0)).*
```

**UPDATE**

The below matches all user agent strings for 5, 6, 7 and 8. And none of 9, 10. It does however match one for IE11, returned from .Net using Request.UserAgent

'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)'

```
^.*MSIE [5-8](?:\.[0-9]+)?(?!.*Trident\/6\.0\)).*$
```

Comment: This will match `IE 51` too....use `\b` after `[5-8]`

Comment: Do check if `\b` is available or not in your regex version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a [list of user agent strings across IE versions](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/). To validate the IE 5, 6, 7 and 8 user agent string, you only need to check for "Trident/6.0)" at the end.

Use this regex: `^.*MSIE [5-8](?:\.[0-9]+)?(?!.*Trident\/[5-9]\.0).*$`

See [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/fX3eJ7/4).

**EDIT**:

According to [MSDN User Agent documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503.aspx#TriToken),

> When the F12 developer tools are used to change the browser mode of
>   Internet Explorer, the version token of the user-agent string is
>   modified to appear so that the browser appears to be an earlier
>   version.
>
> This is done to allow browser specific content to be served
>   to Internet Explorer and is usually necessary only when websites have
>   not been updated to reflect current versions of the browser.
>
> When this happens, a Trident token is added to the user-agent string.
>
> This token includes a version number that enables you to identify the version of the browser, regardless of the current browser mode.

```
Token         Description
Trident/7.0   IE11
Trident/6.0   Internet Explorer 10
Trident/5.0   Internet Explorer 9
Trident/4.0   Internet Explorer 8
```

So, the regex should check if the MSIE version is not followed by 'Trident/5.0', up to 'Trident/7.0': `^.*MSIE [5-8](?:\.[0-9]+)?(?!.*Trident\/[5-9]\.0).*$`. It will be necessary to update it when 'Trident/10'+ is released. Or, here it is:
`^.*MSIE [5-8](?:\.[0-9]+)?(?!.*Trident\/(?:[5-9]|1[0-9])\.0).*$`.

Comment: Not 100% I quite understand the checking of Trident/6.0 at the end. Would you mind breaking it down slightly please?

Comment: I meant that removing `(?!.*Trident\/6\.0\))` you will also match 1 user agent string belonging to IE 10.0, `Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/6.0)`. That is the only condition to check for.

Comment: please see the update in my question. The regex is near perfect, but matches one IE11 UA

Comment: @Oblivy: I have updated the answer after checking some more information on MSDN.