# Parsing RFC 7231 User-Agent strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, user-agent

I need to parse arbitrary [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.3) `User-Agent` strings. Is there a way to do so? I found [`ua-parser.js`](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js) but it tries to be "smarter" by attaching semantic value to browser/device/OS/CPU information, and I just need an array of elements where each has a name and version and optional comment.

I think I could do this via a single regular expression, but the comments make it tricky. Maybe something like `` /([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+.^`|~-])\/([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+.^`|~-])\s+(\([^)]+\))?/ ``, where

- `` [A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+.^`|~-] `` is a `token` as described in RFC 7230 (used twice, once for the name and once for the version)
- `\s+(\([^)]+\))?` is required whitespace optionally followed by non-parentheses characters surrounded by parentheses

but this doesn't handle multiple sub-User-Agent strings and I am not sure whether I missed something in defining comments.

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, but here is [an answer of mine dealing with user agent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29296626/3832970).

Comment: thanks; I don't want to search for *particular* user agents, I just want to split the `User-Agent` string into its components. (reliably.)